# Debug symbols not stripped from resulting binaries in Yocto

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake, openembedded, recipe

**Background**

I am trying to build a custom software inside Yocto build. Software is built by CMake.

The following is my recipe - `customsoftware.bb`:

```
SRCBRANCH = "master"
SRCREV = "master"

MY_SRC = "OMITTED"

SRC_URI = "${MY_SRC};branch=${SRCBRANCH}"

# libraries dependencies
DEPENDS += "boost"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
B = "${WORKDIR}/build"

PARALLEL_MAKE ?= "-j 1"

inherit cmake

# My CMake Options
EXTRA_OECMAKE+=" -DSOME_OPTION=ON"

# I want unix makefiles instead on ninja build
OECMAKE_GENERATOR="Unix Makefiles"
```

The following is a watered down version of my cmake project - `CMakeLists.txt`

*Please note: I have omitted irrelevant parts for brevity*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# set default build to release
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" CACHE STRING "Choose Release or Debug" FORCE)
endif()

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/bin)

set(CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD ON)
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES  ON)

if ("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "
    ${BoldRed}Error:${ColourReset} In-source builds are not allowed. You should create separate directory for build files.
    ${Magenta}CMAKE_BINARY_DIR${ColourReset}(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}) must be different from ${Magenta}CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR${ColourReset}(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
    ")
endif ()

project(myapp)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread) 

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${HEADERS}
  ${SOURCES}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

#Copy entire contents of dist/ to /opt/myapp
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/
    DESTINATION /opt/myapp
)
```

I have appended my recipe to image.

**Issue**

When I ran `du -h tmp/work/.../<customsoftware>/build/dist/bin` binary size is 80MB. Also, after deploying to target system binary size is 80MB.

**UPDATE**

As suggested in comments, binaries at `tmp/work/.../<customsoftware>/image` are not stripped. However, binaries at `tmp/work/.../<customsoftware>/packages-split` are stripped.

If I ran `make` in source of app - not through recipe and outside yocto - binary size is 1.7MB

**Question**

If I remember correctly, OE build will strip debug symbols from resulting binaries.

Why does my binary still get deployed with debug symbols? What have I missed?

How can I make sure only stripped - Release type - binary is deployed?

Comment: look into tmp/work/.../<customsoftware>/image to see what is staged for installation (this is where normally cmake installs files), and what you have in tmp/work/.../<customsoftware>/packages-split should already be stripped, if I recall correctly (this is what is processed by bitbake mechanics in package.bbclass). Try to use `file` utility to see if the binary (in both, image/ and packages-split/ directory is stripped or not).

Comment: Yes, this.  If you want to see what's in a package, actually look in the package.  dpkg can unpack the ipks or dpkgs in `tmp/deploy`, and rpm2cpio can unpack the rpms.

Comment: @Kuchara binaries at <customsoftware>/packages-split are stripped. The ones at <customsoftware>/image are not. Any idea how to put stripped binaries inimage?

Comment: Define packages you want to install into image in IMAGE_INSTALL variable. https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-IMAGE_INSTALL In your case that most likely be the same as <customsoftware>.

Comment: @Kuchara , I have already added my package to image: `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " <customsoftware>"`. Package is present on image, however it is not stripped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly specifying package types and inheriting pkgconfig solved my issue. Updated recipe:

```
SRCBRANCH = "master"
SRCREV = "master"

MY_SRC = "OMITTED"

SRC_URI = "${MY_SRC};branch=${SRCBRANCH}"

DEPENDS += "boost"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

PARALLEL_MAKE ?= "-j 1"

inherit pkgconfig cmake

EXTRA_OECMAKE+=" -DSOME_OPTION"
OECMAKE_GENERATOR="Unix Makefiles"

# Specify package types
PACKAGES = "${PN}-dbg ${PN}"


FILES_${PN}-dbg += "\
    <INSTALL_PATH>/.debug \
    "

FILES_${PN} += "\
    <INSTALL_PATH>/* \
    "
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to see if this simple Hello World is stripped or not in your environment?

recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple helloworld cmake"
LICENSE = "MIT"
SECTION = "examples"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = 
"file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://CMakeLists.txt \
           file://helloworld.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit cmake

EXTRA_OECMAKE = ""
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)
project(helloworld)
add_executable(helloworld helloworld.c)
install(TARGETS helloworld RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

helloworld.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello World Makefile from CMake!\n");
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Yes, it is stripped. I guess `install(TARGETS helloworld RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)` in CMakeLists did the trick. However, my cmake project is fairly complex and I have to install entire `dist/`. Also, I can try separating install: install binaries, install files etc.

Comment: Thanks for testing! This means you setup is OK. It's just, as you say, something funny/more complex in your CMake files :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind about debug version
you can do

```
OECMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE += "-s"
OECMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE += "-s"
```

It will strip your binaries